# Java - alternative to loading large file into memory

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program that loads a large file into the memory, loading it line by line, into an array. One line = one index in the array. Each line of data needs to be "used / processed". I then have a static AtomicInteger in the main class as well. I create multiple worker threads, and each worker thread, gets the data it needs by calling `MainClass.array[MainClass.atomicint.getAndIncrement()]`

This works, but now that I am starting to use larger files, I am getting out of memoery errors, etc. How can I do this so that I don't get out of memoery.

Comment: Load a part of the data into the array, then consume the data. Repeat this until your file is completely processed.

Comment: Is there a reason behind needing to do this? You can just allot more memory to java.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a Thread adding lines to an ArrayBlockingQueue.  It could check the queue is never too large to avoid an OOME.  You can also have a pool of threads reading this queue to get the next task.

Comment: If you use an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a restricted capacity you don’t need to check anything. The queue will block the producer once it is full.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load the whole file into memory. Load it line by line as needed.

Have one class to read the lines of the file. Not all lines, but one line at a time.
Then make your threads call this class, asking for new lines. When the class returns null it is because there are no more lines to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, loading a whole file into memory is bad practice, because your memory requirement may be arbitrarily large — specially when the file is provided by the user. What you want is to read it and process it in chunks, eg.:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile"))) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        process(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `for(String line; ((line = br.readLine()) != null; ) { `